# Use jquery callback instead of RPC in SignalR hub

Tags: javascript, jquery, signalr, jquery-callback, signalr.client

I need to subscribe to the same hub several times from different places, e.g.:

```
function firstPlace(targetHub){
  targetHub.client.onSomeEvent = function(data){
     alert('hello from first place');
  };
}
function secondPlace(targetHub){
  targetHub.client.onSomeEvent = function(data){
     alert('hello from second place');
  };
}

firstPlace($.connection.clientHub);
secondPlace($.connection.clientHub);
```

I'd like to have functionality based on callbacks (like [jquery callbacks](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.callbacks/)).

```
function firstPlace(targetHub){
  targetHub.client.onSomeEvent.add(function(data){
     alert('hello from first place');
  });
}
function secondPlace(targetHub){
  targetHub.client.onSomeEvent.add(function(data){
     alert('hello from second place');
  });
}


firstPlace($.connection.clientHub);
secondPlace($.connection.clientHub);
```

I know it can be easily implemented using some proxy object, but maybe there are some javascript magic that i'm not aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't help yourself, no one else will =). Here is the code, that solve my problem:

```
signalR.FunctionToCallback = new function() {
  self.MapCallback = function (sourceFunction, targetCallback) {
      if (!sourceFunction) {
          sourceFunction = function () {
              sourceFunction.callbacks.fireWith(this, $.makeArray(arguments));
          };
      }
      if (!sourceFunction.callbacks) {
          sourceFunction.callbacks = $.Callbacks();
      }
      sourceFunction.callbacks.add(targetCallback);
      return sourceFunction;
  };
};
```

Usage example:

```
function firstPlace(targetHub){
  targetHub.client.onSomeEvent = ko.FunctionToCallback.MapCallback(targetHub.client.onSomeEvent,function(data){
     alert('hello from first place');
  });
}
function secondPlace(targetHub){
  targetHub.client.onSomeEvent = ko.FunctionToCallback.MapCallback(targetHub.client.onSomeEvent, function(data){
     alert('hello from second place');
  });
}
firstPlace($.connection.clientHub);
secondPlace($.connection.clientHub);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use my EventAggregator proxy like

```
function firstPlace() {
   signalR.eventAggregator.subscribe(MyApp.SomeEvent, this.onSomeEvent, this);
}

function secondPlace() {
   signalR.eventAggregator.subscribe(MyApp.SomeEvent, this.onSomeEvent, this);
}
```

Of course the library has more featurs, but this is one of them

https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/SignalR.EventAggregatorProxy/wiki

Comment: I've read your wiki, and there are too much features it your project for me (I don't want to do any configuration changes on server side for this functionality). Is there are possibility to hook up client side listener only changing client side? I tried to initialize your Event aggregator by myself (var my aggregator = new signalR.EventAggregator();) but it throws multiple errors (Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'client' of undefined jquery.signalR.eventAggregator-1.3.110.0.min.js:1
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'genericConstructor' of undefined )